# Cakephp dynamic add/remove div with jquery and save data in multiple tables

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

I am building a Cakephp 2+ web application. I have implemented dynamic add/remove div containing inputs from user using jquery and now wants to save collected data in multiple tables (right now 2 tables using $belongsTo). The problem is that I am not able to save the data as desired. Also it doesn't show in debug or print_r methods. Please anyone help me if I have something wrong in jquery or in cakephp functionality. What I have done so far is given below:

**JQuery**

```
<script language='javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=1;
var chk=0;

$('.btnAdd').click(function(event){
var inputHtml = '<div class="invoice2_bottom_inner" id="divin"><div class="invoice2_bottom_1"><div id="divno" style="margin:53px 0 0;">1</div></div><div class="invoice2_bottom_delete"><button id="cls" class="close btnRemove">&times;</button></div><div style="float:left; height:auto;width:660px;margin:0;"><table class="table invoice2_payee"><tr><td>Date</td><td>Payee</td><td></td></tr><tr><td><select class="span2" name="data[Expense][date][month][]" id="ExpenseDateMonth"><option value="01">January</option><option value="02">February</option><option value="03">March</option><option value="04">April</option><option value="05">May</option><option value="06">June</option><option value="07">July</option><option value="08">August</option><option value="09">September</option><option value="10">October</option><option value="11">November</option><option value="12" selected="selected">December</option></select>-<select class="span1" name="data[Expense][date][day][]" id="ExpenseDateDay"><option value="01">1</option><option value="02">2</option><option value="03">3</option><option value="04">4</option><option value="05" selected="selected">5</option><option value="06">6</option><option value="07">7</option><option value="08">8</option><option value="09">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select>-<select class="span2" name="data[Expense][date][year][]" id="ExpenseDateYear"><option value="2032">2032</option><option value="2031">2031</option><option value="2030">2030</option><option value="2029">2029</option><option value="2028">2028</option><option value="2027">2027</option><option value="2026">2026</option><option value="2025">2025</option><option value="2024">2024</option><option value="2023">2023</option><option value="2022">2022</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012" selected="selected">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option></select></td><td><input class="input-medium" name="data[Expense][payee][]" maxlength="25" type="text" id="ExpensePayee"/></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Type</td><td> Description</td><td>Amount</td></tr><tr><td><input class="span3" name="data[Expense][type][]" maxlength="25" type="text" id="ExpenseType"/></td><td><input class="input-medium" name="data[Expense][desc][]" maxlength="25" type="text" id="ExpenseDesc"/></td><td><span>$</span><input class="input-mini" name="data[Expense][amt][]" type="number" id="ExpenseAmt"/></td></tr></table></div></div>';

   chk=1;
  $('#divno').attr('id','divno'+i);
  $('#divin').attr('id','divin'+i);
  $('#cls').attr('id','cls'+i);
   $('#divno'+i).html(i);

        //alert(inputHtml);
    event.preventDefault();
$('<div />',{'class':'invoice2_bottom_inner1', id:'div'+(i+1)}).append(inputHtml).appendTo('.invoice2_bottom');
    //$('.invoice2_bottom').append(inputHtml);
    $('.btnRemove').show();
       //alert(i);

if(chk==1)
{
//alert(chk);
$('#divno').attr('id','divno'+(i+1));
$('#divno'+(i+1)).html(i+1);
$('#divin').attr('id','divin'+(i+1));
$('#cls').attr('id','cls'+(i+1));

chk=0;
}
i++;
        var c=$('#cls'+i).attr('id');
        $('#cls'+i).click(function(){
        $('#divin'+i).remove();
        //alert(c);
        if(c=='cls2'){$('.btnRemove').hide();}

        i--;
        });    

});
});
</script>
```

**Cakephp**

Controller:

```
debug($this->data);
    $this->loadModel('Expense');
            $this->Expense->create();
            //if ($this->Expense->save($this->data)){
            if ($this->Expense->saveAll($this->data['Expense'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data has been saved**********'));
                //$this->redirect(array('plugin'=>'agency_calendar','controller'=>'Events','action' => '/add/job/invoice/expense_reports'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The data could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
```

View:

In view I am using static div containing user's input collecting data to be there when page loads for first time and with the help of jquery I am making it in array i.e. 0,1,2 and so on according to Cakephp saveAll method.

Regards

Comment: Are you really going to store that string of DOM elements in the js variable inputHtml? Why not make it html markup in the document and clone it as needed? And, why are you adding an extra array index to your input names? data[Expense][payee][]. Remove the last [], it's likely the root of your problem.

Comment: Thanx Tim for your reply. Inadvertently an array index is given in the last, actually it is like this data[Expense]['counter'][payee] where 'counter' is 'js' counter. And will you please give some example how to clone it as I have almost tried everything but didn't get any success. also I have inputHtml in my view to display it when the page loads for first time and thereafter it is handled by jquery

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably get flagged for this so read it quick as it doesn't pertain to your initial question.

Simple clone example:

```
<div class="clone_handler" style="display:none;">
   <div class="some_class">
      <div>Some nested element</div>
   </div>
</div>

//JS
$(function(){
   var my_clone = $('.clone_handler').clone();
   $('body').prepend(my_clone.children('.some_class'));
});
```